# Solve the riddle - Queen, Tank, Olive, NaCl

Tags: riddle

Common theme riddle:

Fit for a Queen
Fill up your Tank
Olive, Sunflower
NaCl
Under the Bridge
Upon a star

Comment: Are you sure this should be tagged [mathematics]?

Comment: Same question...@Ethan Parker

Comment: @Ethan You should accept Grumpyllama's answer if it is correct. Otherwise, please leave a comment saying it isn't so we know to move on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fit for a queen

> castle

Fill up your tank

> gas

Olive, sunflower

> oil

NaCl

> salt

Under the bridge

> water

Upon a star

> wishing

Answer:

> All of the answers are types of wells